# What is "better" modifying in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm not sure what "better" is modifying in a sentence with "had better":

"If there is a virus in your system, you had better hope that it responds to the appropriate treatment and therapy."

I know it's some sort of idiomatic expression, but what is it modifying in particular?

Answer (score 1):

"had better" in this case refers to "hope". "Had better" can be replaced with "should"

Answer (score 0):

The combination of "had better" and "hope" sounds distinctly odd, by the way. "Had better" is more assertive than "should".